# CSS Width Property Not Getting Set

Tags: css, width

I will try to explain myself as best I can because I really don't want to have to copy all the code over (there is a lot).
I have a span which is getting text from an AngularJS binding (not important to this question) and I am setting four style parameters to this span:

- A width: 100px
- white-space: nowrap;
- overflow: hidden;
- text-overflow: ellipsis;

I am doing this based on the following W3Schools page: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_text-overflow

I want the text to be clipped at 100px and ellipsis added to the end of it.
Here is a screenshot of what is going wrong:

[image: The Google Chrome debugger computed style page for the container of the span]
[image: The Google Chrome debugger computed style page for the actual span]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't apply a width to inline elements like that.

Example:

### HTML

```
<span>1</span>
<span class="blocked">2</span>
```

### CSS

```
span
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 300px;
}

span.blocked
{
    display: block;
}
```

### JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sygap/

Comment: You, my friend, are a lifesaver! Question: how do you know this? I really want to get better at JS, CSS, etc.

Comment: How do I know this? I've made this mistake many a time! Practice, practice and more practice.